# Add target="_blank" to get_categories() WordPress code

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I need to add `target="_blank"` to links I'm retrieving using this PHP code on a WordPress+WooCommerce installation:

```
$products = wc_get_products([
    'status' => 'publish', 
    'limit' => -1, 
    'product_cat' => 'talleres'
]);

$locaciones = array_map(function ($product) {
    return [
        // more code goes here, I just deleted it for this question
        'popup_html' => $product->get_categories() // this is where I need the target="_blank"
    ];
}, $products);
```

I tried with jQuery:

```
  $(document).ready( function(){
    $('a').attr('target', '_blank');
  });
```

But it is not working, it doesn't add the `target="_blank"` to the link.

I'm thinking maybe this can be added directly to the PHP code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a php regex filter like [preg_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) and search by "href" and replace the match putting the target="_blank" before the href resulting in "target='_blank' href"

Comment: you don't even need a regex search, if you use str_replace, it's enough

Answer (score 0):

You may use this script. you need to add class or parent div of Anchor tag otherwise it will add to all anchors.

```
jQuery(document).ready( function($){
    $('a').each(function(){
       $(this).attr('target', '_blank');
   });
  });
```

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work. It doesn't add anything to my links.

Answer (score 0):

Since I needed to open all and every link on a new tab, I just used `<base target="_blank">` for the entire page.